# How to properly share api types from NestJs to Vue (any FE actually) App

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, nest, dto

I have a Front End app written in VueJs and Typescript.
I also have a server written in PHP that is currently being converted to NestJs.
It all lies in the same Monorepo so I have shared types for DTOs.
I'd really love if it was possible to create some kind of helper that will understand the routes in Nest and will create some Interfaces in Typescript for them so when I'll do some post/get to some route, it will have the Typescript types for this route.

Is it possible? Am I fantasizing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this doc from NestJS: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction.

The Swagger package from NestJS can generate an OpenAPI spec which is an industry standard for defining APIs https://swagger.io/specification/ -- Once you have an OpenAPI file, you can do a lot of cool things with it.

For example, you can generate Typescript types, generate entire backends, or frontend API callers on top of libraries such as `axios` or `fetch` that are all strongly typed. You can even generate frontend clients for multiple languages from a common API spec. You can do so with OpenAPI generators (or you can write your own ;)). https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-fetch

So to summarize, steps you can take are:

1. Generate an OpenAPI file from your NestJS routes (NestJS has a package for this)
2. Once you have an OpenAPI specification (as a JSON file), use an OpenAPI generator to generate the types *and* even an entire frontend module to call your API.

Comment: So it is not the other way around, I can't generate a FE API using TS definitions?

Comment: Much harder to do, it's possible by extracting reading the Typescript AST since type information doesn't exist at run-time like a JSON object would.  A project that you find interesting is: https://trpc.io/